# Change factor levels in R using a variable for BOTH factor name AND level order in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame 1 with a lot of columns that are factors. I want to change factor level order for each factor.

I have a lookup data frame 2 for the right factor level orders. This means I can refer to the lookup data frame using a variable for the factor. I can grab the order and put it in a different variable. So far so good.

Simplified example:

```
d = tibble(
  size = c('small','small','big', NA)
)
d$size = as.factor(d$size)

levels(d$size) # Not what I want.

proper.order = c('small', 'big') # this comes from somewhere else
```

I can use `proper.order` to change one column in d.

```
d$size = factor(d$size, levels = proper.order)

levels(d$size) # What I want.
```

I want to refer to the column name (`size`) using a variable.

This doesn't work:

```
my.column = 'size'

d[names(d) == my.column] = factor(d[names(d) == my.column], levels = proper.order, exclude = NULL)


levels(d$size) # What I want.
d # Not what I want.
```

I expect to see the factor reordered. This happens. I expect the factor to keep its values (obviously). They are all set to NA.

I suspect this is because `d[names(d) == my.column]` is a tibble, not a factor. But then why do factor levels change? And how can I reach into the tibble and grab the factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple columns, we can specify in `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(my.column), 
        list(~ factor(., levels = proper.order, exclude = NULL)))
```

---

Or with `fct_relevel` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
d %>%
    mutate_at(vars(my.column), list(~ fct_relevel(., proper.order)))
```

Comment: Thanks. `list` isn't necessary if it's one function, right? so, for mutate_at,
`d %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(my.column), 
        ~ factor(., levels = proper.order, exclude = NULL))`
would work too?

Comment: @petyar It also works, but it is recommended to wrap with `list`